# Dead Button on Web Page (JavaScript/HTML)

Tags: php, javascript, html

Does anyone know why a button would stop working?  There's an onclick javascript event attached to it, and when I click it, I don't see the alert saying that it has fired.  For all intents and purposes, it's dead.

What I am asking is what are some of the causes of this?

I had this happen on a seperate section of the same page, and found I had a curly brace missing, and I have gone through the code where the broken button resides and there is not an issue with the curly braces.  I'm not missing semicolons either.  I know you all will want to see code, but all I am asking about is if someone has had this happen and what was the cause or what were the causes of it happening.

I've already used http://www.javascriptlint.com to comb through the code.

Thanks,
Waddler.

Comment: the button could have a duplicate ID, but without seeing your code...

Comment: Some code snippets would be real useful.

Comment: As stated.  Can't trouble shoot code that we cant see.  Also, look in the Javascript console of whatever browser you are in, its probably generating an error.

Comment: If I were to post the code, I would have to post the entire thing.  @PeteLeaning had the right idea.  I felt it was going to be way too much to post.  If it were a small snippet, sure, but it is too much.  And besides, I addressed the code issues in my OP.

Comment: Look at [JS Lint](http://jslint.com/), and see what it says. Fix the errors it finds (and there are *definitely* errors). And, if you can't post your code we can't help you with anything specific (an esoteric use of an operator, a miscast variable or anything else...) so I'm afraid I have to vote to close as either 'too localized' or 'not a real question.'

Comment: I agree with David Thomas.  If Waddler can't give us a link to a (non-)working example or post the relevant chunk of code, this is too vague for us to help. I don't know if I have the privilege to vote to close, but I'm with David Thomas on that.

Answer (score 0):

This happens in some browsers as they are unable to understand certain versions of javascript.  This could be a browser workaround issue. Try testing in multiple browsers.

Comment: I will try other browsers if/when I can.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a tendency to stop working when it encounters an error.  You may have an error on your page that's not directly related to the code that's no longer running but is preventing it from ever being executed.

You should install a tool like Firebug in Firefox or use one of the other browser's developer's tools.  In firebug, if you run your page with the console open you can see a log of any javascript errors that are encountered and find out if that's the case.  It also allows you to debug the code by setting a breakpoint and following the execution line-by-line and find out if something's not happening the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any code snippets, so it's hard to help when you don't show us anything.

Only advice I can give you: If you are in Chrome or FireFox, Press `Ctrl+Shift+J` to pull up the error console in order to see what the error is.

Comment: Thanks Sam.  I did not know this was available in those browsers.  I have Firebug installed on Firefox, but it was doing me little good because nothing was happening.  I didn't post the code because (a) I was looking for more of a conceptual solution or just things that people have come across before that has caused this and (b) it was a lot of code to post (the section I'm working is a 9 part profile editing section for a jobs website).

Comment: Nothing more than what firebug showed, but it was very useful since I was able to click the error and it brought me to the line of where the error was.  It didn't show any errors when I clicked on the dead button either.  My coworker has been reassigned my portion of that work, so I don't have to worry about it.